# How to insert an special character repetitively in jsx using javascript?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, special-characters

I want to achieve this `<div>&#169;&#169;&#169;&#169;</div>` using js, I tried with `<div>{"&#169;".repeat(4)}</div>` but the result is one string inside the tags `<div>"&#169;&#169;&#169;&#169;"</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render an array of fragments:

```
<div>{Array(4).fill(<>&#169;</>)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do this programmatically, `map` is one solution:

```
  const generateNeededDiv = (number) => {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        Array.apply(null, Array(number)).map(elem => {
          return <span>&#169;</span>
        })
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Call `{generateNeededDiv(4)}` in the JSX where you need it.  Alternatively, if you don't want to use a function, you can take the div being returned and hardcode it to 4. The code with `Array.apply(null,Array(number))` is just initializing an empty array you can iterate over.